# setConsoleIcon throwing weird error (Undocumented WinAPI to JS-Ctypes)

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, jsctypes

There's this undocumend winapi fetarue called `setConsoleIcon`. I discussed with this guy here:

https://github.com/john-peterson/john-peterson/issues/1#issuecomment-47852560

The C++ code is this:

```
void SetIcon(LPCTSTR icon) {
    HMODULE hMainMod = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    HICON hMainIcon = ::LoadIcon(hMainMod, icon);
    HMODULE hMod = LoadLibraryA("Kernel32.dll");
    typedef BOOL (CALLBACK *InsHook)(unsigned long, HANDLE);
    typedef DWORD (__stdcall *SCI)(HICON);
    SCI pfnSetConsoleIcon = reinterpret_cast<SCI>(GetProcAddress(hMod, "SetConsoleIcon"));
    pfnSetConsoleIcon(hMainIcon);
    FreeLibrary(hMod);
}
```

I converted it to this:

```
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm');

var kernel32 = ctypes.open('kernel32.dll');
var user32 = ctypes.open('user32.dll');

var SetConsoleIcon = kernel32.declare('SetConsoleIcon', ctypes.winapi_abi, ctypes.voidptr_t, // i have no idea what return value is so made it voidptr_t
    ctypes.voidptr_t // HICON
);

 /* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
* HANDLE WINAPI LoadImage(
* __in_opt_ HINSTANCE hinst,
* __in_ LPCTSTR lpszName,
* __in_ UINT uType,
* __in_ int cxDesired,
* __in_ int cyDesired,
* __in_ UINT fuLoad
* );
*/
var LoadImage = user32.declare('LoadImageA', ctypes.winapi_abi, ctypes.voidptr_t,
    ctypes.voidptr_t,
    ctypes.char.ptr,
    ctypes.unsigned_int,
    ctypes.int,
    ctypes.int,
    ctypes.unsigned_int
);

var IMAGE_BITMAP = 0;
var IMAGE_ICON = 1;
var LR_LOADFROMFILE = 16;


var aDOMWindow = window;
var baseWindow = aDOMWindow.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
.getInterface(Ci.nsIWebNavigation)
.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIDocShellTreeItem)
.treeOwner
.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
.nsIBaseWindow;

var nativeHandle = baseWindow.nativeHandle;
var targetWindow_handle = ctypes.voidptr_t(ctypes.UInt64(nativeHandle));


var hIconBig = LoadImage(targetWindow_handle, 'C:\\Users\\noit\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\1agqx535.default2\\profilist32.ico', IMAGE_ICON, 256, 256, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
var hIconBigNull = LoadImage(null, 'C:\\Users\\noit\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\1agqx535.default2\\profilist32.ico', IMAGE_ICON, 256, 256, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
var void = SetConsoleIcon(hIconBig); //SetConsoleIcon(hIconBigNull);
```

If you comment out the final line and copy and run this you get no problems.

However if you uncomment it and use it with `hIconBig` or `hIconBigNull` you get this error:
(difference between two, is to `hIconBig` I pass window handle and to `hIconBigNull` i pass null as handle)

```
/*
"missing variable name
WCA_evalWithDebugger@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/devtools/server/actors/webconsole.js:1069:7
WCA_onEvaluateJS@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/devtools/server/actors/webconsole.js:734:9
DSC_onPacket@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/devtools/server/main.js:1098:9
LDT_send/<@resource://gre/modules/devtools/dbg-client.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/devtools/server/transport.js:279:11
makeInfallible/<@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/devtools/DevToolsUtils.js:84:7"
*/
```

I can't explain this `missing variable name`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is your `var void = ...`. `void` is a reserved keyword in Javascript and therefore cannot be used in as a variable name.

Other random observations:

- Use `ctypes.void_t` when declaring functions that are `void` or where you don't care about the return value.
- Never call [`LoadImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with a window handle. It is supposed to be called with a module handle or null. You'll want to call it with null, since you're loading stand-alone images.
- Using undocumented APIs is not a very good idea in general, and should be avoided if feasible. I know that first getting the console window handle with `GetConsoleWindow()` and then sending `WM_SETICON` works just fine, and that is using documented functionality.
- I have no idea what you're trying to do here anyway. Firefox has (normally) no console window at all.

Comment: Aw dang console window wont work :( In Win7 I was not able to set the icon of firefox in the taskbar when its "not pinned". It apparently has a seperate icon when it's pinned and not-pinned. The pinned method I'm working on in other topic using that `SHGetWindowProp` stuff. Ah oh well it was just research I'll keep looking thanks man.